# Allowed amount of input wreal data type at verilog-ams

Tags: cadence, mixed-signal, virtuoso, verilog-a

I'm a newbie at using Verilog-ams and also I want to write a module for flash ADC for a specific application.

I need to confine my voltages reference so I wrote this Verilog-ams code for testing input allowed value at wreal data type.

I arranged a test bench for my code that the inputs are a sinus voltage with 6 V amplitude and a clock signal for the Sequential circuit in Verilog code.
output is an 8-bit signal, consider that is 8-bit-ADC.

as you can see in the first figure below the first change happened at 0.1 volt but it shouldn't happen and then I was expected in the second figure, it change at 1 volt on input in but it didn't happen.

in the end, I don't know what I did here incorrectly.

regards

here is my code

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can not write "if(0<in<1)".
I know that's a bad mistake by programmers but I didn't get any error on the compiler so I thought that it was not a problem.